# Yii file field posting empty values

Tags: php, yii

I am a newbie in Yii, and I am trying to make an upload form in Yii, Please i need help.

Once the form post data to the controller every other post value is posted except for the file value.
i even tried checking for Errors with `var_dump($model->image);` and it returned this Error         `string '' (length=0)` specifying an empty string like an image wasn't even posted at all.

This is my controller

```
 class TestController extends Controller
    {

public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model=new Test;
        if(isset($_POST['Test']))
        { 
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Test'];

                   if($model->save()){
                       var_dump($model->getErrors());

                   if ($model->image){
                          var_dump($model->image);
                         $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
                         $fileName = date("Y_m_d_H_i_s").$uploadedFile;
                         $model->image = $fileName;
                         if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                         {
                           $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/imagefolder/'.$fileName);
                         }
                   }
          }

         }

    }

}
```

And this is my View

```
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'test-form',
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?> 

<?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model,'image',array('id'=>'primaryupload')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'UPLOAD' : 'UPLOAD',array('id'=>'submit','class'=>'btn')); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Because i am really frusrated at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only new to Yii and not in PHP, than you may know that uploaded files goes via `$_FILES` global variable and not via `$_POST` global variable. So to get uploaded file, you use

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
```

So your final code looks like this:

```
$post = Yii::app()->request->getPost('Test');    

if ($post) { 
    $model->attributes = $post;
    $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

    if ($uploadedFile) {
       $imageName = date("Y_m_d_H_i_s").$uploadedFile->name;
       $model->image = $imageName;

       if ($model->save()) {
           $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/imagefolder/'.$imageName );
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your ans, It worked just fine. Although i am having issues also learning how to use multiple upload in Yii

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use $_FILES['image'] instead of $model->image.

Comment: Thanks Navneet for your reply, I tried that..But didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can "hardcode" file attribute in your form. Just:

```
<input type="file" id="yourid" name="yourname" />
```

Then in YourController, where you are parsing your POST data you could directly access to $_FILES['yourname'].

Not an elegant way, but simple and fast.

P.S.: if you are using $this->beginWidget in your view, then you should add to parameters

```
$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    ...
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'
    ),
));
```